# Ruby non-blocking read to use with serial and keyboard input?

Tags: ruby, io

I'm currently writing a light application that handles IO on the serial port, standard input(keyboard) and output (screen). This allows interaction with software embedded on an external board linked to the PC with serial over USB.

I mainly use the `read_nonblock` function and it works well on Linux:

```
$c = $usb_ios.read_nonblock(500)
$in = STDIN.read_nonblock(500)
```

I tried to use it on Windows, but I had an error using `read_nonblock`, then I learned that `read_nonblock` cannot be used on Windows.

After reading lot of posts, FAQs, and blogs, I cannot find a simple way to have some kind of non-blocking read on the serial port. (There might be a dirty way for keyboard input.)

Please note that I don't want to use the 'serialport' gem for several reasons. In fact I want it to work with regular, basic, versions of Ruby.

Comment: What's with the use of `$` globals? They're like instant code-smell.

Comment: Have you considered using threads?

Comment: Tin man => $ global is not the problem here, at now it is only test code so it may change in future

Comment: Lurker => I read in various posts that thread does not solve the problem because Blocking read will block all thread on windows. I don't know if it's worth a try